# How do I figure out why a JQuery ajax request failed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request that should be good that is failing. And there's no information as to why. My code is:

```
$.getJSON( "http://localhost:62178/document?filename=c:/test/dave.docx", function( data ) {
    console.log("read = " + data);
}).done(function(e) {
    console.log( "second success" );
})
    .fail(function(e) {
        console.log( "error" );
    })
    .always(function(e) {
        console.log( "complete" );
    });
```

According to fiddler the REST query is returning a 200 and the returned body is my expected JSON. It is calling fail(e) and the object e is a bunch of functions and the only 3 properties are:
readyState: 0
responseText: ""
statusText: "error"

The generated JSON is created by ASP.NET Web API 2 and so I'm very confident that it's valid. And it does look valid. It is in the form:

```
{
success: true,
document: {
...
  }
}
```

How do I figure out what JQuery is unhappy with?

**Update:** I figured out the problem (cross domain request). But my original question remains, how do I figure out why an ajax request failed from the vars passed in the fail() function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .fail function after the getJSON call (like you have it already) and output the parameters like so:

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){ //ERROR
    console.log('FAILURE: ' + textStatus);
    console.log(jqXHR);
});
```

Now look in the console and you can see the textStatus and you will see the jqXHR object. This object contains additional information that might be helpful. Let me know if this works or if something is unclear! Thanks!

Comment: console.log(jqXHR); prints out "result = undefined" and the value of textStatus is "error".

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this in your fail.

```
.fail(function(xhr){
  Response.Write
  alert(xhr.responseText);
  }
```

Comment: Hi - I get "xhr is not defined". And what is the purpose of Repoonse.Write? That is not a valid javascript statement. Am I not understanding something?

Comment: `function(e)` should be `function(xhr)`